# Unable to Reverse Geocode From Marker Click

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm trying to put together the reverse geocode functionality for [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/allmyfindstest.html) page, where the user clicks on a map marker and the reverse geocode is performed, populating a text field with the output address.

I thought I had the issue sorted out after I received some great advice from this site, but I just can't seem to resolve the issue I have.

I can populate the text fields with the marker lat and lng co-ordinates but I just can't get any ouptut from the reverse geocode.

I've gone through the code with JS Fiddle and there are no issues with the Javscript and I've been looking at some of the online tutorials, but I just don't know where I'm going wrong.

I just wondered whether someone could take a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been through my code again, and realised it wsn't quite right.

The reverse geocode script should look like this:

```
(function reversegeocode() {


            var lat = document.getElementById('findosgb36lat').value;
            var lng = document.getElementById('findosgb36lon').value;

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            getAddress(latlng);

            return false;
        }

    )

    function geocodePosition(pos) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            latLng: pos
        },

        function(responses) {
            if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
            } else {
                updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
            }
        });
    }

    function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
        document.getElementById('address').value = str;
    }

    function getAddress(latlng) {

        if (!geocoder) {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        }

        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': latlng
        }, function(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
// Looping through the result
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
if (results[0].formatted_address) {

                document.getElementById('address').value = results[0].formatted_address;
            }

    }
    }
    }
    )
    }
```