# Click location on Map to find closest locations

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

This code takes a list of addresses in a database and finds the locations closest to an inputted address.  I'm wondering if it's possible to just click a location on the map and have it find the closest locations that way instead of entering the address.  Anyone know how to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/vibajajo64/Lroa81am/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js"></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">  

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script> 

  <style type="text/css">
     html,
 body,
 #map {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 600px;
   width: 400px;
 }

 .text {
   width: 300px;
   height: 600px;
   background-color: white;
   overflow: scroll;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
 }

 #side_bar {
   z-index: 100;
   position: absolute;
   top: 135px;
   left: 400px;
 }

 #panel {
   z-index: -100;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 135px;
   left: 400px;
 }

 #mdiv {
   z-index: 500;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   display: none;
   background-color: red;
   border: 1px solid black;
   position: absolute;
   left: 660px;
   top: 112px;
 }

 .mdiv {
   height: 25px;
   width: 2px;
   margin-left: 12px;
   background-color: black;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   /* Safari and Chrome */
   z-index: 1;
 }

 .md {
   height: 25px;
   width: 2px;
   background-color: black;
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
   /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
   /* Safari and Chrome */
   z-index: 2;
 }

 tr:nth-child(even) {
   background: #CCC
 }

 tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background: #FFF
 }
 .numberCircle {            
  /* float: left; */            
  border-radius: 50%;           
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);       
  /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
  width: 18px;              
  height: 18px;             
  padding: 4px;             
  margin: 0px;              
  background: #fff;         
  border: 2px solid #666;       
  color: #666;              
  text-align: center;           
  font: 16px Arial, sans-serif;     
}                   

  </style>

  <title> by vibajajo64</title>







<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

var locations = [
  ["John Doe", "145 Rock Ridge Road, Chester, NY ", "41.314926,-74.270134", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["Jim Smith", "12 Williams Rd, Montvale, NJ ", "41.041599,-74.019554", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John Jones", "689 Fern St Township of Washington, NJ ", "40.997704,-74.050598", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],


];
// alert(locations.length);

var geocoder = null;
var map = null;
var customerMarker = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var closest = [];
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  // alert("init");
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6699927, -0.7274620),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "found " + locations.length + " locations<br>";
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var coordStr = locations[i][2];
    var coords = coordStr.split(",");
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
    bounds.extend(pt);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pt,
      map: map,
      icon: locations[i][3],
      address: locations[i][1],
      title: locations[i][0],
      html: locations[i][0] + "<br>" + locations[i][1] + "<br><br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;" + locations[i][1] + "&quot;);'>Get Directions</a>"
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })
      (marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  $("#mdiv").click(function() {
    $("#side_bar").css({
      "z-index": 100,
      "top": "135px"
    });
    $("#panel").css("z-index", -100);
    $("#mdiv").css("display", "none");
  })

}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
      customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location, 12);
      // get driving distance
      closest = closest.splice(0, 12);
      calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest, 12);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function findClosestN(pt, numberOfResults) {
  var closest = [];
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing " + gmarkers.length + "<br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt, gmarkers[i].getPosition());
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process " + i + ":" + gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + ":" + gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2) + "<br>";
    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
    closest.sort(sortByDist);
  }

  return closest;
}

function sortByDist(a, b) {
  return (a.distance - b.distance)

}

function calculateDistances(pt, closest, numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request = {
    origins: [pt],
    destinations: [],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
    request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  }
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      var sidebarHtml = '<table>';

      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      // save title and address in record for sorting
      for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
        results[i].title = closest[i].title;
        results[i].address = closest[i].address;
        results[i].idx_closestMark = i;
      }
      results.sort(sortByDistDM);
      for (var i = 0;
        ((i < numberOfResults) && (i < closest.length)); i++) {
        closest[i].setMap(map);
var letterMarkers = String.fromCharCode(97 + i);
closest[results[i].idx_closestMark].setLabel(letterMarkers);
       sidebarHtml += "<tr><td><div class='numberCircle'>" + letterMarkers + "</div><a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' + results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' approximately ' + results[i].duration.text + "<br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;" + results[i].address + "&quot;);'>Get Directions</a></td></tr>"

      }
      sidebarHtml += '</table>';
      outputDiv.innerHTML = sidebarHtml;
    }
  });
}

function getDirections(origin, destination) {
  var request = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      $("#side_bar").css({
        "z-index": -100,
        "top": "135px"
      });
      $("#panel").css("z-index", 100);
      $("#mdiv").css("display", "block");

      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));


    }
  });
}

function sortByDistDM(a, b) {
  return (a.distance.value - b.distance.value)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="bh-sl-container">
  <div id="page-header">
    <h1 class="bh-sl-title">The Auditor Locator</h1>

  </div>

  <div class="bh-sl-form-container">
    <form id="bh-sl-user-location" method="post" action="#">
      <div class="form-input">
        <label for="bh-sl-address">Enter Address or Zip Code:</label>
        <input id="address" type="text" value="Paramus, NJ" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="codeAddress();" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <table border="0" style="height:100%">
    <tr style="height:100%">
      <td style="height:100%">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="side_bar" class='text'></div>
        <div id="panel" class='text'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <div id="info"></div>
  <div id="mdiv">
    <div class="mdiv">
      <div class="md">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script>
  // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
  if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
      height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
      slug: "Lroa81am"
    }], "*")
  }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457406/unable-to-reverse-geocode-from-marker-click#8458291 maybe?

Comment: That seems like you have to enter a latitude and longitude, etc.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a event listener to bind the click, then you can run a function to do whatever you need.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
    codeAddressByClick(event.latLng)
}); //end addListener
```

And to get closest locations, you can set a function to get the click/event Lat and Lng and then call `findClosestN()`, like follow:

```
function codeAddressByClick(locationLL) {
        closest = findClosestN(locationLL, 12);
        // get driving distance
        closest = closest.splice(0, 12);
        calculateDistances(locationLL, closest, 12);
}
```

Also you can fit bounds when clicked:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
       codeAddressByClick(event.latLng);
       //fitbounds of the click position
       var newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(event.latLng,event.latLng);
       map.fitBounds( newBounds );
       map.setZoom(9);
    }); //end addListener
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/h0Lr0jen/

EDITED:

> Using Google Reverse Geocoding to populate the search field with the address based by the clicked position.

A slight change need to be done on the parameter passed to `codeAddressByClick()` and a `Ajax` call to Google Maps Geocoding API need to be made in order to get the actual address by the geocode.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
    codeAddressByClick(event)
}); //end addListener
```

Then:

```
function codeAddressByClick(locationV) {
        closest = findClosestN(locationV.latLng, 12);
        closest = closest.splice(0, 12);
        calculateDistances(locationV.latLng, closest, 12);
        //MAKE AJAX CALL TO GOOGLE API BY CLICKED LAT & LNG CLICK POSITION
        jQuery.get( "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + locationV.latLng.lat() + ',' + locationV.latLng.lng(), function( data )
        {
         if(data.results[0].formatted_address){
          //POPULATE THE ADDRESS FIELD
          jQuery('#address').val(data.results[0].formatted_address);
         }
        });
}
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h0Lr0jen/1/

Comment: Wow, really neat!! Anyway to have the address you click on the map to show up in the search box just so you could see where you clicked?   Thanks so much.

Comment: You will need to have a look on `reverse  geocoding` [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding). In your application you will have to make a Ajax call to the Google API to retrieve the address and then populate your search field. if this answer helps votes up :)

Comment: The reverse geocoding link you provided works great but I'd have no idea how to do the ajax call to the Google AP to retrieve the address and then populate the search field.  Can anyone show an example.  Thanks

Comment: Alright, I would recommend you to have look at [jQuery ajax method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to understand how it works. And also on [this one](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to understand how to populate fields... I will be glad if you study and understand these basics :)... BTW If you see my updated answer you will see it working...

Comment: Thanks for the great links, will have to go over them thoroughly to learn this myself.  Looks like you did an awesome job!!  Thanks so much!!